# PHP append multiple child to a DOM element

Tags: php, xml, dom

i'm trying to append multiple child elements to a XML Element but the result is not what I expected.

Im doing this: ($this->conceptos is an array of information)

```
$XMLCFDI = new DomDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
$comprobante = $XMLCFDI->createElement("cfdi:Comprobante");
$c = $XMLCFDI->appendChild($comprobante);

$NodoConceptos = $XMLCFDI->createElement("cfdi:Conceptos");
$attNodoConceptos = $c->appendChild($NodoConceptos);

foreach($this->conceptos as $conceptos) {

        $itemElement = $XMLCFDI->createElement('cfdi:Concepto');
        $itemElement = $attNodoConceptos->appendChild($itemElement);
}
```

i want something like this:

```
<cfdi:comprobante>
    <cfdi:conceptos>
        <cfdi:concepto/>
        <cfdi:concepto/>
        <cfdi:concepto/>
    </cfdi:conceptos>
</cfdi:comprobante>
```

But my result is:

```
<cfdi:comprobante>
    <cfdi:conceptos>
        <cfdi:concepto>
            <cfdi:concepto>
                <cfdi:concepto>
                </cfdi:concepto>
            </cfdi:concepto>
        </cfdi:concepto>
    </cfdi:conceptos>
</cfdi:comprobante>
```

Somebody could help me?

Comment: How do you know the result is that one? I checked your code and it already gave me the expected result. Check: [https://eval.in/613016](https://eval.in/613016) (copy the result and format it)

Comment: Note that since you want to end up with 3 `concepto` (in the example), and you don't use the value from the array loop, I just created one to loop 3 times... That's the only difference

Comment: just found this with your answer, if i print the result with print_r got the wrong option but if i use var_dump got the correct

Comment: Well, it also works with `print_r` for me: [https://eval.in/613036](https://eval.in/613036)

Comment: The generated XML is not valid. `cfdi` is an undeclared namespace prefix. To create and element with a namespaces use `$XMLCFDI->createElementNS($namespace, "cfdi:Conceptos");`. `$namespace` should contain the actual namspace urn. https://eval.in/613099